# Fuel meter on Yamaha TZR 50/125

Tags: motorcycle

I have my eyes on my childhood dream, Yamaha TZR 125.
But, as it turns out,  this motorcycle doesn't have any type of fuel meter.

[image: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c2/Yamaha_TZR_125_1991_cockpit.jpg]

And,  I'm pretty sure,  it doesn't have any sensor for it too.. 
So,  my question is,  is there a way to add some sort of,  custom made or buyd,  fuel meter to this motorcycle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not do that. To do the real one is a lot of work to do. Open the tank, find the swimmer, do and seal a hole, find modules to regulate the swimmer and then the right fuel meter. It's also pretty danger. Maybe you will find an other tank with a fuel meter in it and right module for it.

Comment: So,  my best bet is to find another fuel tank,  with the sensor inside,  that fit my bike?

Comment: Yes, I think it's the best and easiest way to do that.

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure what is used is just mileage calculation to figure out how many miles are left in a tank of gas. Other than that, you pop the cap off, look down the hole and see how much fuel is in the tank. Once you have been riding the bike for a while, you'll know just how far a tank of gas will carry you and also be able to tell by the slosh in the tank about how much gas is in there so you'll know when to fill up. IMHO, trying to add a tank which will give you an option for a gauge is not a good way to go, especially if (at least this is the way it sounds) you really like the bike. If you really like the bike, then you must like the aesthetics of the bike as well, which means if you change the tank, it will most likely be ugly in your eyes. It will appear as if something is just not right. Don't rely so much on electronic or mechanical gizmos to tell you how much gas is left, figure it out the old fashioned way and make riding your bike that much more fun.

Comment: Yup, that's the old skool method.    :-)

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a dual tank for the machine. When I was riding my BSA C12 many years ago, some machines, not mine, had a tap on the tank to switch between a reserve tank and a main tank. The reserve tank was inside the main tank. Me-I relied on taking the filler cap off and looking inside before/during a trip.

Answer (score 0):

2-stroke bikes don't usually have a fuel meter. The premix is adjustable by the rider and your mileage may vary, so not much point in putting one on, since it wouldn't be very useful.